# Azure Storage account: uploading files with an SaS Url is still blocked by firewall

Tags: typescript, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a simple webapp that user can use to share files.

The user will upload a file to Azure blob storage. The way to achieve this is as follows:

1. The user selects a file from local and click the upload button;
2. A request is send to backend service running in Azure VM, which will create a URL with SAS key, and responds to the request.
3. The user gets the URL with SAS key in his browser, and then the frontend uploads the file by sending PUT request to this SAS Url.

The code to generate SAS Url is:

```
export function generate_AzureBlob_signed_url(CONTAINER_NAME, BLOB_NAME) {
  
  const ACCOUNT_NAME = process.env.AZURE_BLOB_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME as string;
  const ACCOUNT_KEY = process.env.AZURE_BLOB_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_KEY as string;
  // const CONTAINER_NAME = process.env.AZURE_BLOB_STORAGE_CONTAINER_NAME;

  // TODO: must change to using User Delegation SAS instead of using access key, for security best practices;
  const sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(ACCOUNT_NAME, ACCOUNT_KEY)
    
  //This URL will be valid for 1 hour
  const expDate = new Date(new Date().valueOf() + 3600 * 1000);

  // Generate service level SAS for a blob
  const blobSAS = generateBlobSASQueryParameters({
    containerName: CONTAINER_NAME, // Required
    blobName: BLOB_NAME, // Required
    permissions: BlobSASPermissions.parse("racwd"), // Required  // todo: refine the permissions furthur; maybe to specific http methods? 
    startsOn: new Date(), // Optional
    expiresOn: expDate, // Required. Date type
    cacheControl: "cache-control-override", // Optional
    contentDisposition: "content-disposition-override", // Optional
    contentEncoding: "content-encoding-override", // Optional
    contentLanguage: "content-language-override", // Optional
    contentType: "content-type-override", // Optional
    ipRange: { start: "0.0.0.0", end: "255.255.255.255" }, // Optional
    protocol: SASProtocol.HttpsAndHttp, // Optional
    version: "2019-12-12" // Optional
  },
  sharedKeyCredential 
  ).toString();

  const SaSURL = `https://${ACCOUNT_NAME}.blob.core.windows.net/${CONTAINER_NAME}/${BLOB_NAME}?${blobSAS}`;
  console.log(`SAS URL for blob is: ${SaSURL}`);
  return SaSURL;
}
```

SAS URL for blob is:

```
https://myapp.blob.core.windows.net/issues/issues/src-HosE/dst-HosX/2023-08-31-18-44/b01e7dd3cb2ea333/raw/BJFC00272274T500_006.dcm?sv=2019-12-12&spr=https%2Chttp&st=2023-08-31T09%3A44%3A28Z&se=2023-08-31T10%3A44%3A28Z&sip=0.0.0.0-255.255.255.255&sr=b&sp=racwd&sig=JIAZVvddUI5FQ1DGNIMhJQUajxOxHduzfLNq%2F4OhlIA%3D&rscc=cache-control-override&rscd=content-disposition-override&rsce=content-encoding-override&rscl=content-language-override&rsct=content-type-override
```

To Break it down:

```
https://myapp.blob.core.windows.net/issues/issues/src-HosE/dst-HosX/2023-08-31-18-44/b01e7dd3cb2ea333/raw/BJFC00272274T500_006.dcm
?
sv=2019-12-12 &
spr=https%2Chttp &
st=2023-08-31T09%3A44%3A28Z &
se=2023-08-31T10%3A44%3A28Z &
sip=0.0.0.0-255.255.255.255 &
sr=b &
sp=racwd &
sig=JIAZVvddUI5FQ1DGNIMhJQUajxOxHduzfLNq%2F4OhlIA%3D &
rscc=cache-control-override &
rscd=content-disposition-override &
rsce=content-encoding-override &
rscl=content-language-override &
rsct=content-type-override
```

However, now at step 3: the browser report 403 error:

```
PUT https://myapp.blob.core.windows.net/issues/issues/src-HosE/dst-HosX/2023-08-31-18-44/b01e7dd3cb2ea333/raw/BJFC00272274T500_006.dcm?sv=2019-12-12&spr=https%2Chttp&st=2023-08-31T09%3A44%3A28Z&se=2023-08-31T10%3A44%3A28Z&sip=0.0.0.0-255.255.255.255&sr=b&sp=racwd&sig=JIAZVvddUI5FQ1DGNIMhJQUajxOxHduzfLNq%2F4OhlIA%3D&rscc=cache-control-override&rscd=content-disposition-override&rsce=content-encoding-override&rscl=content-language-override&rsct=content-type-override 

403 (This request is not authorized to perform this operation.)
```

Now, in the Azure Storage Account's portal page, in `Networking --> Firewalls and virtual networks --> Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses`

Once I add the user's ip address under firewall rules, the file upload succeeds.

Looks like even though there is the SaS Url, the upload PUT request is still blocked by firewall rules.

Without selecting `Enabled from all networks` for the Storage account networking settings, how can I allow users from any public internet to upload files to Azure storage with an SaS Url?

Coming from AWS S3, I can make a bucket not public, while still allow file upload / download to and from the bucket using pre-signed url, from public internet.

I'm looking for something of the same effect..

Answer (score 0):

OK after some research I have found the answer:

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/107721#issuecomment-1498792117

> A SAS (Shared Access Signature) token does not bypass firewall rules
> for a storage account.
>
> Firewall rules for a storage account control network access to the
> storage account based on the client's IP address. SAS tokens are used
> to grant access to resources in the storage account, but they do not
> impact the firewall rules.
>
> If a client's IP address is not allowed by the firewall rules, the
> client will not be able to access the storage account even if they
> have a valid SAS token. Conversely, if the client's IP address is
> allowed by the firewall rules, the client can use a valid SAS token to
> access resources in the storage account.
>
> It's worth noting that you can create SAS tokens that grant access to
> resources from specific IP addresses or ranges of IP addresses, but
> this still doesn't bypass the firewall rules. The firewall rules will
> still apply, and the client's IP address must be allowed in order to
> access the storage account.

and the scenario in AWS S3 works in Azure too, by not enabling the "anonymous access", such that there will only be access through the SAS url you generate, over the public internet.

Just ensure you do not enable ‘anonymous access’.